# How to compare objects in single array and give validation based on previous object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, compare, javascript-objects

I have one array which has n number of objects, suppose if I was having 3 objects, and the value of one property at index 1 is null then the value for the same property is having value in next index it should show error that previous object value shouldn't be blank

Example sample`:[{Id:1, name:'abc'}, {id:2, name:''}, {id:3, name:'dcg'}]`
Here based on iteration as name is empty at index 1 and having value for name at index 2 it should throw error previous object value name cannot be blank. How to achieve this using forEach

Comment: You could simply check the value within an if statement and throw the error for yourself to handle afterwards. You would want to break out of the foreach loop if you do not wish to continue validation the object further.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check items in `forEach` loop and throw a new exception.

If you wanna prevent that error, you can surround your code block with `try catch` clause like the following.

```
const arr = [
  { Id: 1, name: "abc" },
  { id: 2, name: "" },
  { id: 3, name: "dcg" }
];

try {
  arr.forEach(function (x, index) {
    if (index > 0) {
      if (x.name && !arr[index - 1].name) {
        throw "Name is not valid at " + (index - 1);
      }
    }
  });
} catch (e) {

  console.error(e);

  //  Or any error handler here.
}
```